# Selecting which apps are allowed to cancel shutdown

Tags: macos

I find it hard to accept that any app can cancel an otherwise smooth shutdown of my mac.

Is there a setting somewhere that I would be able to approve certain apps, but not others, to the prevent shutdown?

OSX 10.10

Answer (score 1):

An app will always cancel shutdown if it has an open unsaved document which needs your decision as to whether to save or not.

Also, if an app goes unresponsive, the shutdown will time out.

I'm not sure that behaviour can be changed, but I'm open to ideas.